# Caluculating IDF(Inverse Document Frequency) for document categorization

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, tf-idf, document-classification, categorization

I have doubt in calculating IDF (Inverse Document Frequency) in document categorization. I have more than one category with multiple documents for training. I am calculating IDF for each term in a document using following formula:

```
IDF(t,D)=log(Total Number documents/Number of Document matching term);
```

My questions are:

1. What does "Total Number documents in Corpus" mean? Whether the document count from a current category or from all available categories?
2. What does "Number of Document matching term" mean? Whether the term matching document count from a current category or from all available categories?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Total Number documents in Corpus` is simply the amount of documents you have in your corpus. So if you have 20 documents then this value is `20`.

`Number of Document matching term` is the count of in how many documents the term `t` occurs. So if you have 20 documents in total and the term `t` occurs in 15 of the documents then the value for `Number of Documents matching term` is 15.

The value for this example would thus be `IDF(t,D)=log(20/15) = 0.1249`

Now if I'm correct, you have multiple categories per document and you want to able to categorize new documents with one or more of these categories. One method to do this would be to create one documents for each category. Each category-document should hold all texts which are labelled with this category. You can then perform `tf*idf` on these documents.

A simple way of categorizing a new document could then be achieved by summing the term values of the query using the different term values calculated for each category. The category whose term values, used to calculate the product, result in the highest outcome will then be ranked 1st.

Another possibility is to create a vector for the query using the `idf` of each term in the query. All terms which don't occur in the query are given the value of `0`. The query-vector can then be compared for similarity to each category-vector using for example [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

[Smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) is also a useful technique to deal with words in a query which don't occur in your corpus.

I'd suggest reading [sections 6.2 and 6.3](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/scoring-term-weighting-and-the-vector-space-model-1.html) of "Introduction to Information Retrieval" by Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze.

Comment: Thanks..I got an answer. But can you please explain categorizing new document little elaborated?. That is how to get the matching category for new document?. Then how to form frequency vector for new document to do matching?..

Comment: @Sicco I was doing something exactly what you mentioned in the answer. However I have only two categories, so two documents. With such low number of documents my Idf for a word could only be {0, 0.5}, which gets me too loose much information.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small post describing term frequency-inverse document frequency here: http://bigdata.devcodenote.com/2015/04/tf-idf-term-frequency-inverse-document.html

Here is a snippet from the post:

TF-IDF is the most fundamental metric used extensively in classification of documents.
Let us try and define these terms:

Term frequency basically is significant of the frequency of occurrence of a certain word in a document compared to other words in the document.

Inverse Document frequency on the other hand is significant of the occurrence of the word in all the documents for a given collection (of documents which we want to classify into different categories).